# Opening a PNG file with eog where the filename has colon

Tags: eog

I have a PNG file that will not show the content in `eog` and the program reports an error "No images found in". It seems to be a problem with the colon in the filename. With `bash`, I try:

`eog "scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png"`

the program opens, but reports

`No images found in “scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18t17:///00:33.717199.png”.`

The same error message is displayed for

`eog scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17\:00\:33.717199.png`

With `gimp` there is no such problem:

`gimp scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17\:00\:33.717199.png`

opens and displays fine. A renaming will do it:

```
cp "scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png" tmp.png
eog tmp.png
```

opens and displays fine.

I am wondering whether there is an error in `eog` or I am somehow using it the wrong way?

Interestingly, the `scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png` file will open fine with the "open" in the menu.

Comment: A possible workaround might be to prepend a relative (or absolute) path ex. `eog "./scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png"`

Comment: I am using gimp 2.10.8 and it gives a similar error message `Opening 'scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18t17:///00:33.717199.png' failed: Location is not mountable` .  To solve this use the file like this: `'./scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png'`

Comment: I see. This is apparent a similar problem I had with scp https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148929/how-do-i-copy-a-file-with-scp-with-special-characters

Comment: I see that eog is apparently able to open files from the web, so the colon may confuse the interpretation of the string as a url/filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to such "problems" is to use a slash (`/`) somewhere *before* the colon (`:`). For example:

```
eog './scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png'
gimp '/full-path/scholia-pageviews-2019-11-18T17:00:33.717199.png'
```